# Evaluation error: Caused by error in JavaScript probe

Tags: javascript, middleware, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am working on Mid Server with Service Now, I defined a 'Mid Server Script Include' Javascript Class and when I try to call it with a Background Script, I got this error message in ECC queue input:

`Evaluation error: Caused by error in JavaScript probe`

To resolve this, I tried to update the maximum Script included because by default, the system caches 250 script includes when the MID Server runs. If the MID Server needs to run a script that is not cached, the MID Server fails and produces an error. But I still have the error. My Mid Server is running and up.

Do you know how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide details about the code you run?
Have you tried to run a total barebones version of the code yet?